# How to maintain dropdown list after it selected through URL?

Tags: html, url

for example I have this URL
http://oursite.com/WebSite5/production/ReportPage.aspx?name=&office=VTM

on dropdown list VTM is selected, but in unable to select another option.

[image]

How can I maintain the dropdown list item like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Follow this code to add a dropdown link like as second image

```
<label for="country">Country:</label>
        <select name="country" id="countryselect">
            <option value="0" selected disabled>Select Your Country</option>
            <option value="Sri Lanka"> Sri Lanka</option>
            <option value="Qatar"> Qatar</option>
            <option value="Moldova (Republic of)"> Moldova (Republic of)</option>
            <option value="Korea (Democratic People's Republic of)"> Korea (Democratic People's Republic of)</option>
            <option value="Åland Islands"> Åland Islands</option>
        </select>
```

You can use a **selected** attribute to Add always selected option and **disable** attribute mean it can't select to user.